# how can I make columns and rows equal size and length on Vue?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

[image: pic]

AS you can see from the image none of the columns and rows align and are all different sizes. im quite new to javascript and vue and would really appreciate the help.from what i uunderstand on the internet the v-row is supposed to auto make the the row aswell as the v-col according to the amount of elements in the v-col howerver it soes not work. i must be doing something wrong?

```html
<template>
  <div class="calculator">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row >
          <div class="display">10</div>
        <v-col>
          <v-btn class = "btn">c</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "btn">+/-</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "btn">%</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "operator">÷</v-btn> 
        </v-col>

        <v-col>
          <div></div>
          <v-btn class = "btn">7</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "btn">8</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "btn">9</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "operator">x</v-btn>
        </v-col>

        <v-col>
          <div></div>
          <v-btn class = "btn">4</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "btn">5</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "btn">6</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "operator">-</v-btn>
        </v-col>

        <v-col>
          <div></div>
          <v-btn class = "btn">1</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "btn">2</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "btn">3</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "operator">+</v-btn>
        </v-col>

        <v-col>
          <div></div>
          <v-btn class = "btn zero">0</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "btn">.</v-btn>
          <v-btn class = "operator">=</v-btn>
        </v-col>

      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default{
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.calculator {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px,auto);
}

.display {
background-color:black;
grid-column: 1 / 5 ;
}

.zero {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  
}

.btn {
  font-size: large;
  color:black;
  background-color: rgb(236, 232, 232);
  border: 1px sold black;
}

.operator {
  font-size: large;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 1px sold black;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is your App.vue wrapped in <v-app> component?

Comment: @NehaSoni no it is not.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this format:

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        <v-main>
            <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
                <v-row no-gutters>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="4">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            resuiltsd
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row no-gutters>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row no-gutters>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row no-gutters>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row no-gutters>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>
                <v-row no-gutters>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                    <v-col cols="4" sm="1">
                        <v-card class="pa-2" outlined tile>
                            One of
                        </v-card>
                    </v-col>
                </v-row>

            </v-container>
        </v-main>
    </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: this did not work it just copied the values four times beside each other and they still kept getting smaller.

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that your app is wrapped inside `v-app` component and that your root element has an `id app`. This is often a reason for styling to not work.**

If your provided code is inside the `App.vue` then try this-

```
<div id="app">
 <v-app>
  <div class="calculator">
    <v-container>
      <v-layout row>
        <div class="display">10</div>
        <v-flex>
          <v-btn class="btn">c</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn">+/-</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn">%</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="operator">÷</v-btn>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex>
          <div></div>
          <v-btn class="btn">7</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn">8</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn">9</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="operator">x</v-btn>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex>
          <div></div>
          <v-btn class="btn">4</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn">5</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn">6</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="operator">-</v-btn>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex>
          <div></div>
          <v-btn class="btn">1</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn">2</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn">3</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="operator">+</v-btn>
        </v-flex>

        <v-flex>
          <div></div>
          <v-btn class="btn zero">0</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn">.</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="operator">=</v-btn>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </div>
</v-app>
</div>
```

And if this code is inside any child component then make sure your `App.vue` is wrapped correctly.

**App.vue**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <ChildComponent />
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Tip:-**
If this works then you no longer needed custom styling to arrange your elements in a grid format. Vuetify will handle this using rows and column.

**EDIT-**

Use `v-flex` instead of `v-col`, as you are on Vuetify's 1st version.

Comment: Ok, I added v-app to my App.vue 
However, it still does not work I also added your code.

Comment: `<div id="app">` is outside the `<v-app>`. Please check my code above.

Comment: yes, i pasted your code, it still, however, produces the same results.

Comment: Maybe you can provide any codepen so I can check it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it in some time if you'd don't mind.

Comment: The snippet you provided is not correct. Well, here you can see- https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-template-forked-f5wkh0?file=/src/components/Calculator.vue

Comment: it still is wrong when I paste it on my code. I don't understand why could it be Safari. or something i have not downloaded